# What's the significance of a quasi-static process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

Is there a problem, if my thermodynamic process is not quasi-static?

I have read the definition that a quasi-static process is an infinitesimally slow process in which every intermediate state of a system brought from one equilibrium state to another is at equilibrium.

But I can't figure out its significance.

Comment: You may have a look at this previous question and answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452085/what-is-quasi-static-process?rq=1 . Do they answer your question?

Comment: @GiorgioP Curiously the definition in the link implies that only an adiabatic process is quasi-static.

Comment: @BobD, yes, but the mistake was clarified in the answers, including yours.

Comment: @GiorgioP Oops. I shoulda looked down further.

Comment: @GeorgioP .. I have gone through the question and answer. But it's not relevant to what I have asked. I wish to know why quasi-static process have this much importance.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of quasi static processes is precisely that they can be considered to involve a system that is permanently in equilibrium, both within itself and with its surroundings. This is crucial in order to have well-defined state variables such as the temperature or the pressure of the system, which are defined only for systems **in equilibrium**.

Thus, if one pretends to track the value of these variables as one progresses along a thermodynamic process, the process needs to be quasi static. Otherwise one can only speak of their value before and after the process is over and the equilibrium has been restored.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, here is the text rewritten in Physics Stack Exchange markdown with math enclosed in $ $:

---

The concept of a quasi-static process in thermodynamics is indeed central to understanding and analyzing thermodynamic systems, particularly in the context of deriving and applying fundamental principles. The significance of a process being quasi-static can be understood from several perspectives:

**Thermodynamic Equilibrium**: In a quasi-static process, the system remains infinitesimally close to equilibrium at all times. This means that at each infinitesimal step, the system's properties (like pressure, volume, temperature) can be well-defined, and the system is in internal balance. In contrast, non-quasi-static processes involve rapid changes where the system may not be in equilibrium at each moment, leading to undefined or non-uniform thermodynamic properties.

**Reversibility**: Quasi-static processes are often associated with reversible processes, though they are not exactly the same. A reversible process is an idealized quasi-static process where, in addition to the system being in equilibrium at all steps, there are no dissipative effects like friction or turbulence. In practical terms, most quasi-static processes are not perfectly reversible due to such irreversibilities.

**Thermodynamic Paths and State Functions**: For quasi-static processes, it is possible to define a clear thermodynamic path between the initial and final states of the system. This is crucial for calculating work done and heat transfer, as these depend on the path taken. In a non-quasi-static process, since the system is not in equilibrium at each step, defining a thermodynamic path becomes problematic, and concepts like work and heat become more complex to handle.

**Applicability of Thermodynamic Laws**: Many fundamental laws and equations in thermodynamics, like the ideal gas law or the equations for calculating work and heat, assume the system is in (or very close to) equilibrium. These laws might not be directly applicable or may require modifications when dealing with non-quasi-static processes.

When dealing with a non-quasi-static process, several complications arise:

- **Undefined State Variables**: Thermodynamic variables like pressure and temperature may not be uniform or well-defined throughout the system.
- **Irreversible Processes**: These processes typically include irreversible components, making the analysis more complex as entropy generation and dissipative effects need to be considered.
- **Difficulty in Calculation**: Calculating work and heat transfer becomes more challenging, as these quantities are path-dependent and the path is not well-defined in non-equilibrium states.

In summary, while quasi-static processes provide a foundational and simplified model for understanding thermodynamic systems, real-world processes are often non-quasi-static. This necessitates a more complex analysis, considering non-equilibrium thermodynamics, and often involves empirical or numerical approaches to fully understand and predict the behavior of the system.

Answer (score 0):

A quasi static process is an (ideal) process where the system remains in *internal* equilibrium at all time, but not in equilibrium with the *external* environment.

Internal equilibrium implies that intensive parameters like temperature and pressure are defined at all times.

Since equilibrium with the external environment isn't required for a quasi static transformation, temperature and pressure of the system don't need to be equals to those of the environment. However, in practice, *mechanical* equilibium is usually considered established at all time because it settles very quickly, while *thermal* equilibrium isn't.

To sum it up, during a quasi static process:

- $P$ and $T$ are defined (all other intensive parameters)
- $P=P_\text{ext}$ (mechanical equilibrium)
- $T\neq T_\text{ext}$ (unless the process is also isothermic of course)

Making a process quasi static has two advantages:

- It allows you to speak about $T$ and $P$ during the process.
- It allows you to write the first law of thermodynamics for any short time intervall $[t,t+dt]$ as: $dU=\delta W+\delta Q$.

Comment: The first paragraph is very enlightenting. Can you please elaborate on your last bullet? First law holds irrespective if the process is quasi static or not.

Comment: The first law is indeed universal, but it requires that both initial and final states be equilibrium states. So if you take two instants $t$ and $t+dt$ in the middle of a process, the system has no reason to be in equilibrium and the first law has no reason to apply… unless the process is quasi static.

Answer (score 0):

If a system initially at equilibrium in state 1 is moved to state 2, then it will not be necessarily in equilibrium in this latter state, so one will have to wait for some time that it relaxes to equilibrium. This also implies that the entropy of the system will increase and such a transformation definitely would not be reversible.

In a quasistatic process the system evolves from one state to another very slowly, so that it always remains in equilibrium (with negligeable corrections). The final state is thus an equilibrium state, and the process can be reversible (in principle, but it doesn't have to.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use thermodynamic reasoning to understand the outcomes of both quasistatic and non-quasistatic processes, but in order to analyse the latter you first have to understand the former. Also the reasoning process will yield more information for the quasistatic case.

The conservation of energy for a closed system gives
$$
dU = \delta Q + \delta W
$$
which is true for any process (quasistatic or not). Clausius' theorem asserts
$$
\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ge 0
$$
for any cycle, with equality only in the reversible case. This also is true for any process (quasistatic or not) except of course that reversible processes must be quasistatic. For a non-quasistatic process the $T$ in this formula refers to the temperature of that part of the system at which the heat transfer takes place (the rest of the system need not have a well-defined temperature).

The great value of quasistatic processes is that we can consider the system state at each stage to respect the various equations of state for equilibrium states.
Things like pressure and temperature are well-defined throughout (which is not always true for non-quasistatic processes).
So for an ideal gas for example you would have $pV = nRT$ at every stage but this is usually not going to be true for non-quasistatic processes (during the process). Similarly you can relate the internal energy to the system parameters, and you can use the equilibrium values of heat capacities, compressibilities, susceptibilities etc. This means we have a great deal more information to work with.

To sum up, thermodynamic reasoning gives detailed information about quasistatic processes throughout the process. Dealing with non-quasistatic processes it can also make a few global statements about things like energy and entropy, and it can be used to relate changes in any function of state to any other function of state once the system has reached equilibrium at the end of any given process.